How to compute a list of statistics on a Polars dataframe?
I have the following dataframe with two columns Cost and StartTime.
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Cost": [1, 2, 3],
    "StartTime": [datetime(2023, 6, 23), datetime(2024, 6, 22), datetime(2024, 6, 21)],
})

shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Cost ┆ StartTime           │
│ ---  ┆ ---                 │
│ i64  ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞══════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2023-06-23 00:00:00 │
│ 2    ┆ 2024-06-22 00:00:00 │
│ 3    ┆ 2024-06-21 00:00:00 │
└──────┴─────────────────────┘

I would like to compute the mean and total cost - once for the entire dataframe and once for only the year 2024. I'd like the result to be stored in a single dataframe.
How can this be achieved in python polars? Thanks!
Edit. Here is an example that separately computes each of the summary statistics.
total_costs = df.select('Cost').sum()
average_costs = df.select('Cost').mean()
df_2024 = df.filter(pl.col('StartTime').dt.year() == 2024)
total_costs_2024 = df_2024.select('Cost').sum()
average_costs_2024 = df_2024.select('Cost').mean()


Can you post an example input dataframe and the expected output?

Added examples @Dogbert!

input is already a python function so is a bad variable name. You should add the datetime import as it is nonobvious. The output is also a little unclear, do you really want all these values in separate variables? Or do you want to create a "summary dataframe" with all the information contained inside it?

I would like to compute all my desired statistics in a single data structure by exploiting Polars/Python if possible.

How about you write this: df.describe()?

@geometricfreedom I would like to compute my desired statistics, not the ones provided by describe()

Have you tried: df.with_columns(pl.col("Cost").sum(), pl.col("Cost").mean())?

You were on the right track using a pl.DataFrame.select context to compute the statistics. Still, you can pass multiple expressions at once and assign names with pl.Expr.alias. Moreover, there is pl.Expr.filter to filter an expression instead of the entire dataframe.
filter_expr_2024 = pl.col("StartTime").dt.year() == 2024
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.col("Cost").sum().alias("TotalCost"),
        pl.col("Cost").mean().alias("AverageCost"),
        pl.col("Cost").filter(filter_expr_2024).sum().alias("TotalCost2024"),
        pl.col("Cost").filter(filter_expr_2024).mean().alias("AverageCost2024"),
    )
)

shape: (1, 4)
┌───────────┬─────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ TotalCost ┆ AverageCost ┆ TotalCost2024 ┆ AverageCost2024 │
│ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---           ┆ ---             │
│ i64       ┆ f64         ┆ i64           ┆ f64             │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 6         ┆ 2.0         ┆ 5             ┆ 2.5             │
└───────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────┘


Thank you very much @Hericks. Would you mind adding the detail of how to access one of those datum at runtime? I.e. how to index "TotalCost2024" and return the Python float in Polars (there is the beta release 1.0 these days, I don't know if the API is being changed)

@Luco You can use either df.select("TotalCost").item() or df.get_column("AverageCost").item(). Using .get_column() and .select() creates a (single-column) dataframe and series, respectively. Subsequently, .item() produces the python float.
